# which documents need to be in a USPTO provisional utility patent for a software system

Tags: patent-applications, provisional-application, filing, utility-patent

Presently I have:
COVER SHEET
ABSTRACT
and
CLAIMS

What's missing?

Comment: There is no such thing as a provisional patent, only provisional applications.

Comment: For one there is no need for claims. Perhaps you should read the Wikipedia article before asking the question: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Provisional_application